# System.out.print() imprime últimos caracteres dos veces

Tags: java

Tengo esta parte de un código en Java (lo trabajo con Visual Studio Code):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vacaciones2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int clave = 0, antiguedad = 0;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("* Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Company *");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Escriba el nombre del trabajador: ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("¿Cuántos años de servicio tiene el trabajador? ");
        antiguedad = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");  
        
        System.out.print("¿Cuál es la clave del trabajador? ");
        clave = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        teclado.close();
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que me arroja cuando lo corro:

```
*********************************************************
* Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Company *
*********************************************************


Escriba el nombre del trabajador: Travis Parker

¿Cuántos años de servicio tiene el trabajador? r? 10

¿Cuál es la clave del trabajador? ? 2
```

Es decir, después de imprimir la pregunta "¿Cuántos años de servicio tiene el trabajador?" enseguida me imprime un "r?" extra, o sea, me repite la impresión de los últimos dos caracteres del String. Algo parecido pasa con la pregunta "¿Cuál es la clave del trabajador?" como pueden ver.

Soy nuevo en Java así que no tengo idea de por qué pasa esto. Gracias por su ayuda :)

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***

Según sus comentarios me he dado cuenta que el problema probablemente sea mi configuración de Visual Studio Code, ya que si compilo en la terminal de Windows el programa corre sin presentar el error. ¿Saben qué podría estar pasando con mi VSC?

***ACTUALIZACIÓN2***

Acabo de descubrir que los caracteres finales se repiten sólo al usar el print() (al usar el println() no ocurre) y cuando el String a imprimir incluye caracteres como acentos o la letra 'ñ'. Es decir, una línea de código como ésta:

```
System.out.print("¿Cuantos anos de servicio tiene el trabajador? ");
```

no produce la repetición de los caracteres finales. ¿Alguna idea de por qué?

Comment: acabo de probar tu código en vsc,  me funciona bien y no me imprime los últimos dos caracteres como te pasa a ti, no se a que se deba tu problema pero el ide no es y el código tampoco, en mi opinión.

Comment: Al igual que @SalvadorMellado, he probado el código en Eclipse y no he podido replicar tu problema, por lo que el problema es del IDE (configuración) o, en su defecto, de tu configuración de Java.

Comment: Debe de ser mi Visual Studio Code entonces, porque en la terminal de Windows al compilarlo funciona bien! Muchas gracias, ¿alguno sabe qué podrá estar pasando con mi configuración de VSC?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

Después de recoger cada valor, es decir después de las líneas como `nombre = teclado.nextLine();`

Introduce la siguiente línea: `teclado.nextLine();`

Como resultado, tu código quedaría así:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vacaciones2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int clave = 0, antiguedad = 0;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("* Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Company *");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Escriba el nombre del trabajador: ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("¿Cuántos años de servicio tiene el trabajador? ");
        antiguedad = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");  
        
        System.out.print("¿Cuál es la clave del trabajador? ");
        clave = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        teclado.close();
    }
```

Espero que esto te haya funcionado.

Comment: No funcionó :/ pero gracias! Leyendo comentarios el problema debe ser mi configuración de Visual Studio Code porque al compilar en la terminal de Windows no ocurre esa repetición de impresión..